# Where is '/var/log/secure.log' in Mountain Lion

Tags: logging, osx-mountain-lion

I used to check `/var/log/secure.log` for ssh connection attempts.
But since upgrading to Mountain Lion it's gone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to user @ben_fry on twitter, we have an answer. In short, secure.log auth events have been rolled into asl (syslog). Stack won't let me post more than one link so the answer I wanted to post here is on my blog:

http://leoofborg.tumblr.com/post/29470691922/hey-apple-wth-happened-to-secure-log-in-mountain

Note that I have not changed over my denyhosts to use asl so I do not know if this works, but according to the folks on twitter it does.

Comment: The link is broken and now this answer is unhelpful.  Rather than fix the link, maybe post the answer you wanted to post.

Answer (score 2):

This points to the solution: https://twitter.com/ben_fry/statuses/233594227802648577

Or direct: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4149679?start=0&tstart=0

SSH logins are now logged in `syslog`